# How to populate scrapy item list with hardcoded string

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

my Scrapy crawler is working fine, currently he is crawling some tables, but on some website there are not all information on hand which I like to insert into my mysql table. 
So I thought about adding them myself, because on those websites the information is for those fields the same, but I am not sure how to populate them in the spider.

Sure, I could determine the length of one of the lists in the pipeline and then use a while loop to add for example USA in the item['country'] list but I want to do the same in the spider.

I would apppreciate some help, thank you.

Current spider code for populating lists:

```
def parse(self, response): 
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="pagecontainer"]'):
        item = EbayItem()
        item['id'] = sel.xpath('div[2]/text()[2]').extract()
        item['user'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[2]/text()[1]').extract()
        item['string'] = sel.xpath ('tr/td[2]/a/text()').extract()
        item['state'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[3]/b[3]/text()').extract()
        item['country'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[3]/b[1]/text()').extract()         
        item['weight'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[3]/b[2]/text()').extract()
        item['position'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[4]/text()').re(r'[0-9,\-]+')
        item['old'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[5]/text()').extract()
        item['datetime'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[6]/text()').re('[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}')
        yield item
```

Greetings

P.Halmsich

Comment: Do you need something like `item['country'] = 'USA'` in parse()? If not could you give us an example of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add things in MySQL. This means that your fields shouldn't be arrays (e.g. `['my-value']`) but scalars (e.g. `'my-value'`). The easiest way to do this is by using `extract_first()` instead of `extract()`.

`extract_first()` allows you to set default values like this: `.extract_first(default='my-default-value')` or just `.extract_first('my-default-value')`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the scraped item for empty results using `if-else` statement. Try the code below:

```
def parse(self, response): 
for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="pagecontainer"]'):
    item = EbayItem()
    item['id'] = sel.xpath('div[2]/text()[2]').extract()
    item['user'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[2]/text()[1]').extract()
    item['string'] = sel.xpath ('tr/td[2]/a/text()').extract()
    item['state'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[3]/b[3]/text()').extract()
    item['country'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[3]/b[1]/text()').extract()
    if item['country'] == []:
        item['country'] = 'USA'
    item['weight'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[3]/b[2]/text()').extract()
    item['position'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[4]/text()').re(r'[0-9,\-]+')
    item['old'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[5]/text()').extract()
    item['datetime'] = sel.xpath('tr/td[6]/text()').re('[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}')
    yield item
```